# execute "jobs" command in my shell

Tags: c, linux, command

I'm making my own shell in a c program and i need to execute "jobs" command to see list of stopped processes. I tried `system("jobs")` and `execlp("jobs","jobs",NULL)`, but both didn't work, both didn't give me any result and I am sure that there is a stopped process.
So does anyone know a way to execute "jobs" command in a c program?
Thank you

Comment: `jobs` is a shell builtin but should work with `system()` since that runs a shell. However, `system()` will fork a *new* child shell process which will not have any background jobs!   You can only see jobs executed in the *current* shell, not in its parent (which is what you are trying to do).  Since it is not an external program, `jobs` won't work with `execlp`.  If you are writing your own shell then you will have to write your own `jobs` command too.

Comment: (You/the process executing your shell will have to keep track of forked processes/jobs "yourself"/itself.)

Comment: @greybeard okay thanks